# UnitialisedPropertyAccessException even after lateinit var has been initialised?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having issues with some Kotlin code that I have not come across before.

In one activity I declare a late init variable:

```
lateinit var currentUser : User
```

And later on initalise it. I know it is initalised because I used the isInitialized method to double check after I initialise it:

```
private fun instantiateUser(name : String?, email : String?, flatId : String?) {
    currentUser = User(name, email, flatId)
    if(::currentUser.isInitialized) {
        Toast.makeText(this@HomeActivity, "Initialised", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this@HomeActivity, "Not initialised", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I get the expected output, so I know currentUser is initialised. However, when I later call from an activity that runs directly after this one, I get the UnitializedPropertyAccessException at this line:

```
var currentUser = HomeActivity().currentUser
```

Here is the User class in case it is relevant:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User(
    var name: String? = "",
    var email: String? = "",
    var flat: String? = ""
)
```

Any suggestions for what could be causing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: In this way `HomeActivity().currentUser`, actually you create another instance of HomeActivity where `currentUser` is not initialized. Instead of doing that try to pass the object through `intent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `HomeActivity().currentUser` actually you are creating another instance of `HomeActivity` where `currentUser` is not initialized. Check below options:

**Option - 1:** Pass through `intent`

```
Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("CURRENT_USER", currentUser)
    startActivity(this)
}
```

To achieve this you have to make your `User` either **Serializable** or **Parcelable**

```
@Parcelize
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User(
    var name: String? = "",
    var email: String? = "",
    var flat: String? = ""
) : Parcelable
```

**OR**

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User(
    var name: String? = "",
    var email: String? = "",
    var flat: String? = ""
) : Serializable
```

**Option - 2:** You can make your `currentUser` static using `companion object`

```
companion object {
    lateinit var currentUser : User
}
```

And then call like below from other activity

```
HomeActivity.currentUser
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to using one of those options over the other? I've noticed for option 1 I have to use experimental = True. Is this an issue I should be avoiding?

Comment: **Option - 1** is recommended way of passing object between activities

Comment: Between `Serializable` and `Parcelable`, strongly prefer `Parcelable` (and implement with `@Parcelize`)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I use `Serializable` for simplicity. I will update with that options also

Answer (score 1):

To extend **zsmb13**'s answer a bit:

Indeed you are not supposed to instantiate Activities, this is done by the system. If you want to pass a User object to another Activity, the easiest way would be to utilize Kotlin's built-in features and parcelize your User so it looks like:

```
@Parcelize
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User(
        var name: String? = "",
        var email: String? = "",
        var flat: String? = ""
) : Parcelable
```

To pass it to another Activity (**this** refers to `HomeActivity`):

```
val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).putExtra("YOUR_KEY", currentUser)
startActivity(i)
```

And get it in your second Activity, e.g. in `onCreate()`:

```
val user: User? = intent?.getParcelableExtra("YOUR_KEY")
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing down `HomeActivity()` is a call to the constructor of that Activity, and will create a new instance of it. That new instance won't have its `currentUser` property set yet. You should never create Activity instances by hand, but instead let the system do it, [using Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity).

If you want to share the `currentUser` stored inside your `HomeActivity`, you can pass a reference to your existing `HomeActivity` to other classes. If you want to share data between Activities, you can pass it through `Intent` extras, or by saving it to a database and then reading it from there, or by sharing a `ViewModel` between the two Activities.